# My Eclipse's JS file editor's background isn't black

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, aptana

I installed Eclipse and Aptana 3 plugin. My HTML, CSS, XML file editor's background color is black. But only JS file editor's background color is white.

How can I change it to Aptana 3's style (black)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible it's opening it with a Web Tools JS editor or some other editor instead of the Aptana editor? Double-check by choosing right-click "Open With" on the file.

If so, you should be able to set Aptana as the default in Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations.